graph in latex codes
How can i write this ?
i tried matrix enviroment but doesn't work
$\begin{matrix}
1 & & 2 \\
&2&
\end{matrix}$ 

Is there an option that would reduce the gaps?

Please show us what you tried and post a minimal working example (MWE), starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.

The title of your query mentions something about a graph, but the body of your query seems to be more interested in some kind of array of numbers. Please clarify your fomatting objective.

I find that using a matrix environment can work just fine. I suggest creating a two-row three-column matrix, will all cell contents centered. To reduce the intercolumn whitespace, I further suggest choosing a smaller than usual value for the parameter \arraycolsep; its default value in many document classes is 5pt, but for the use case at hand 1pt may be what's needed.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'matrix' environment
\usepackage{xcolor}  % for '\mathcolor' macro
\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt} % default: 5pt
\begin{matrix}
   1 & & 2 \\
   & \mathcolor{red}{2} &
\end{matrix}
\]

\end{document}

